# Load a DLL into a different AppDomain and his dependencies

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, appdomain

I'm having a bit trouble to load a DLL by reflection in a different AppDomain.

This is my scenario.

1. I have a DLL called Interfaces.DLL which only contains an interface Definition.
2. Test.DLL include Interfaces.DLL and define a class called Connector, which implements the interface defined on previous dll.
3. I have an app which only include Interfaces.dll and needs to load Test.dll using reflection
4. I call a public method of class connector which returns me the DLL version of the dll file loaded by reflection. After that, I call a web service to check if i have the greater version of the file. If not, I have to unload the dll, remove the file, and download the new file.

The problem is on step 3. When i try to load Test.DLL in a different AppDomain, i get an error because it cannot find Interfaces.Dll in the AppDomain. The message is:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled
 FileName=BankInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

So, how can I load 2 different Dll in a AppDomain?

This is my code:

**Interface.DLL**

```
Public Interface BankInterface
       Function getDLLVersion() As Double
       'Other methods here
End Interface
```

**Test.DLL**

```
Public Class Connector
    Implements BankInterfaces.BankInterface
    Public Function getDLLVersion() As Double Implements BankInterfaces.BankInterface.getDLLVersion
         Return 2.5
    End Function
```

**MainApplication**

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim domainSetup As New AppDomainSetup
    domainSetup.ApplicationName = appDomainName
    domainSetup.ApplicationBase = "C:\Users\jferrer.GLOBAL\AppData\Roaming\Enterprise\AppName\DllFiles\"

    Dim LocalAppDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("BankDLL" & Guid.NewGuid.ToString.GetHashCode.ToString("x"), Nothing, domainSetup)
    AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve

    LocalAppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom("C:\Users\jferrer.GLOBAL\AppData\Roaming\Enterprise\AppName\DllFiles\TestDLL.dll", "TestDLL.Connector") 'This line throw the error
    Dim conector As Type = LocalAppDomain.GetType()

    'Irrelevant code here
end sub

Private Function CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As ResolveEventArgs) As Assembly
    Try
        Dim myassembly As Assembly = Assembly.Load(args.Name)
        If Not IsNothing(myassembly) Then
            Return myassembly
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    Dim parts As String() = args.Name.Split(",")
    Dim myfile As String = "C:\Users\jferrer.GLOBAL\AppData\Roaming\Enterprise\AppName\DllFiles\" & parts(0).Trim() & ".dll"

    Return Assembly.LoadFrom(myfile)
end function
```

UPDATE:

If I change

```
AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve
```

to

```
AddHandler LocalAppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve
```

I get a warning from Visual Studio:

```
Warning 1   Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated.  C:\Proyectos\BANK\BankTest\Form1.vb 49  20  BankTest
```

And there is no difference between the original behaviour.

Comment: Shouldn't the AssemblyResolve be on the LocalAppDomain?

Comment: It's not necessary. AssemblyResolved is a shared member: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6t76186.aspx

Comment: I know what a shared member is. The [Assembly Resolve Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx) isn't one.

Comment: My mistake, the shared member is CurrentDomain. Please check the update on the original post

Comment: The GAC was made to solve problems like this.  Pretty important to get rid of getDLLVersion(), use the [AssemblyVersion] attribute instead.  You can still use AssemblyResolve to implement your own "GAC", you must hide the DLLs in a subdirectory so the CLR cannot find them.

Comment: You want `LocalAppDomain.AssemblyResolve` not `LocalAppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve`

Comment: I tried it too. When it arrives to that line on execution time i get this error: Can not load file or assembly 'BankTest, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null' or one of its dependencies. The system can not find the file specified. BankTest is the name of the MainApplication

Comment: @HansPassant. How would he download a new version of the dll from a webservice and unload the current one through the GAC? or are you saying he has no need to load the dll in the first place?

Comment: The assembly resolve event is in BankTest, so it needs to load that to hook up the assembly resolve event but you moved the application base. So it can't find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite I have not applied directly the suggestions of @James Barras, his comments help me to find this solutions. So, thanks for take the time to help me :)

This is a posible solution to anyone in my situation:

1. The class you want to deserialize must inheriht from MarshalByRefObject
2. The objects returned by the methods inside your class must be serializable
3. Create this class:

   ```
   Imports System.Reflection

   Public Class Loader
   Inherits MarshalByRefObject
   Private Function CallInternal(dll As String, typename As String, method As String, parameters As Object()) As Object
       Dim a As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dll)
       Dim o As Object = a.CreateInstance(typename)
       Dim t As Type = o.[GetType]()
       Dim m As MethodInfo = t.GetMethod(method)
       Return m.Invoke(o, parameters)
   End Function
   Public Shared Function [Call](dll As String, typename As String, method As String, ParamArray parameters As Object()) As Object
       Dim dom As AppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyNewDomain")
       Dim ld As Loader = DirectCast(dom.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, GetType(Loader).FullName), Loader)
       Dim result As Object = ld.CallInternal(dll, typename, method, parameters)
       AppDomain.Unload(dom)
       Return result
   End Function
   End Class
   ```
4. Use this code to call a method inside the dll you want to load:

   ```
   Loader.Call(pathToDLL, ClasName,MethodName, parameters)
   ```

This solution unload the domain after you call any method. So it is not perfect, because if you want to call several methods, you will be penalized on execution time.